# How to write in Greek in R's ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that there is a way to write individual Greek letters using expression(), but i need to write quite a big text and i cant pick the letters one by one. Is there a solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why are you writing a "big text" in a plot?

Comment: @Roland I initially had the same thought, but honestly after more than a couple letters (i.e. could even occur with legend of not-crazy size), wrapping letters in `expression()` individually would be a pain, so seems like a useful question anyway

Comment: @Roland Its just a 15 something letter title and 5 15 letter legend entries. Its not big, but not comfortable to type out one by one

Comment: How many different greek letters do you have? You could just write a place holder and then use search/replace.

Comment: You could use unicode. `ggplot() + ggtitle("This is a Greek letter \u03A3")`

Comment: Can't you just type "Μeγάλο κeίµeνο" into the console?

Comment: R supports Greek characters as long as you have a font that renders them. If I need to get them into the console I go to Google translate, type the English in, get the Greek translation and paste it into the console.

Comment: @AllanCameron yeah thats as far as it gets but still there are some letters that are not converted like ''e'' that should become ''ε'', so it looks bad on something official

Comment: Please provide example data and code to plot, example Greek text we want to add, and give us more details where we want that text added.

Comment: @Lyngbakr thats the solution, as gilberg said too. ty

Comment: @zx8754 thanks for the help but it got fixed by using encodings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One quick solution would be to convert your Greek characters to UTF-16 with [a tool like this](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter), then add the converted text to your areas just as you normally would.

For example, "Μιλάω ελληνικά" in UTF-16:

> \u039c\u03b9\u03bb\u03ac\u03c9 \u03b5\u03bb\u03bb\u03b7\u03bd\u03b9\u03ba\u03ac

This will print in R and ggplot like any other text:

```
ggplot() + 
ggtitle("\u039c\u03b9\u03bb\u03ac\u03c9 \u03b5\u03bb\u03bb\u03b7\u03bd\u03b9\u03ba\u03ac")
```

Comment: Youre a life saver! It worked perfectly. ty for the tool